# Remove duplicate from a list but not returning two same results in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

```
duplicate([],[]).
duplicate([A|B],[A|B1]) :- not(member(A,B)), duplicate(B,B1).
duplicate([A|B],List) :- member(A,B), duplicate(B,List).
```

I wrote this predicate to remove duplicate from the list, but when I test it,

```
?- duplicate([a,b,c,a,d,c,b,a,e,f],N).
N = [d, c, b, a, e, f] ;
N = [d, c, b, a, e, f] ;
false.
```

Is there a way to just keep one result only, not two same results? (so it will only return one list).

Also, I am not allowed to use operators that modify the backtracking search, such as the cut operator !, the negation operators not, +, or the if-then-else operator with -> and ;

It would be grateful if someone could help me .  :D

Comment: Use `memberchk/2` instead of `member/2`. Also use `\+` instead of `not/1`, as the former is ISO Prolog and the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Also, FYI, only the cut modifies the search procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual reason for receiving more than one answer is the goal `member(A,As)`. It produces multiple answers for duplicates in `As`.

```
?- member(a, [a,a]).
   true
;  true.
```

There are several ways out.

### `memberchk/2` or `once/1`

`memberchk/2` is defined as

```
memberchk(X, Xs) :-
   once(member(X, Xs)).
```

This removes alternate answers.  But then, it may remove otherwise valid solutions too.  Consider:

```
?-        memberchk(X, [a,b]), b = X.
   false.
?- b = X, memberchk(X, [a,b]), b = X.
   b = X.
```

So `memberchk/2` is sensitive to the precise instantiation, which makes it a very brittle, impure predicate.

But it has one good point: It sticks to just one answer for

```
?- memberchk(a, [a,a]).
   true.
```

So what would be ideal is a definition that is both pure and sticking to the first element.  Enter

### `memberd/2`

```
memberd(X, [X|_Ys]).
memberd(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
   dif(X, Y),
   memberd(X, Ys).
```

In this definition, the recursive rule is only of relevance if the list element is different. Thus this rule will never apply to `memberd(a, [a,a,a])`.

Another problem in your definition is `not(member(A,B))` which only behaves as intended, if `A` and `B` are sufficiently instantiated.  Your definition fails for:
`duplicate([a,X],[a,b]).` although there is a solution: `X = b`.

Rather replace it by [`non_member/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322639/772868).

Alternatively, in case you are interested in the most efficient solution, consider `library(reif)` available
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl) which leads to:

```
list_nub([], []).
list_nub([X|Xs], Ys0) :-
   if_(memberd_t(X, Xs),  Ys0 = Ys1, Ys0 = [X|Ys1]),
   list_nub(Xs, Ys1).
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I used memberchk to solve this problem . Thank you for your answer again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to remove all duplicates, not the most efficient but I think it's quite easy to understand the intention.

```
rm_duplicates(In, Out) :-
    exclude(has_duplicate(In), In, Out).

has_duplicate(List, Case) :-
    dif(I, J),
    nth0(I, List, Case),
    nth0(J, List, Case).
```

If you mean to make a list into a set:

```
list_to_set(List, Set).
```

It's documented: [list_to_set/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=list_to_set/2)

Comment: Note that `exclude/3` has an implicit cut which produces incorrect answers like: `B=b,rm_duplicates([a,B],Cs).` succeeds, whereas `rm_duplicates([a,B],Cs).` fails