# implement a prolog predicate that removes all duplicate elements

Tags: prolog

Implement a Prolog Predicate  that removes all duplicate elements from a list given in the first argument and returns the result in the second argument position.

Comment: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2 removes duplicates, as well as sorting.

Comment: Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720605/prolog-how-to-eliminate-duplicates-of-list-of-elements-without-changing-the-ord

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework writing service. What have you tried? Show us your source code. What's not working? See also the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [`list_nub/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144672/772868) for a pure implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibilities. There's just a few cases:

- The source list is the empty list (`[]`). That is a set (**∅**, the empty set) by definition. That give us this:

  ```
  list_set( [] , [] ) .
  ```
- The source list is not empty, and the *head* of the list is duplicated in the *tail* of the list. It this case, since the head can be found elsewhere in the list, it's a duplicate and can be discarded. That gives us this:

  ```
  list_set( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :-
    member(X,Xs),
    list_set(Xs,Ys)
    .
  ```
- Finally, the source list is not empty, and the *head* of the list is **not* duplicated in the *tail* of the list. In this case, since the head is unique, we can add the *head* to the result set. That gives us this:

  ```
  list_set( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-
    \+ member(X,Xs),
    list_set(Xs,Ys)
    .
  ```

That's all there is to it.

Putting it all together you get:

```
list_set( []     , []     ) .
list_set( [X|Xs] , Ys     ) :-    member(X,Xs), list_set(Xs,Ys) .
list_set( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- \+ member(X,Xs), list_set(Xs,Ys) .
```

You might notice the two tests using `member/2`. That can be optimized away by introducing a *cut* (`!/0`) to eliminate the choice point between clauses 2 and 3 of the above predicate. Having introduced that, we can eliminate the second `member/2`, because the only way to get to the third clause is if `X` is unique:

```
list_set( []     , []     ) .
list_set( [X|Xs] , Ys     ) :- member(X,Xs), !, list_set(Xs,Ys) .
list_set( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-                  list_set(Xs,Ys) .
```

Comment: Can *double* the performance by using `memberchk` instead of member. Can test that with:  `numlist(1, 3_000, NL1), numlist(1, 3_000, NL2), numlist(1, 3_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L), time(list_set(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).`